# how to rotate to current of Orientation?

Tags: iphone

according to my code when my device are use in Landscape

when i pushViewController it will

automatic show in UIDeviceOrientationPortrait.

i need to rotate my device to Portrait and then rotate to Landscape,

then it will present in Landscape mode.

how can i rotate to current of Orientation with out use of private API(setOrientation)?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) ||
            (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the status bar orientation:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app setStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape];
[app setStatusBarHidden: NO animated: YES];
```

You can get the current device orientation like this:

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation
```